# Parse a regular string to JSON in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, format

I have the following string in node.js which I get from server

```
{"response":"Name 1: local value1 remote value2  state ACTIVE\nName 2: local value3  remote value4  state ACTIVE"}
```

and I want to convert it to JSON format like the following -

```
{  
                    "response":[
                        {
                            "Name":1,
                            "local":"value1",
                            "remote":"value2",
                            "state":"active"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name":2,
                            "local":"value3",
                            "remote":"value4",
                            "state":"active"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

I cannot use JQuery, because this is on the server side.

I tried doing JSON.parse() but that did not yeild the intended result.

Thanks,
Ganesh.

Comment: Your target format isn't valid json. please clarify.

Comment: If your server suppose to send JSON, than it should be fixed because it's not sending valid nested JSON

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my target JSON. Also, I don't have the luxury of changing the server side response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the response from the server always comes in the format you provided, you can create the JSON you want like this:

```
var json = {"response":"Name 1: local value1 remote value2  state ACTIVE\nName 2: local value3  remote value4  state ACTIVE"};

function parse(json) {
  var responses = json.response.split("\n"),
      regex = /(([A-Za-z0-9]+) ([A-Za-z0-9]+))+/g,
      result = { response:[] };

  responses.forEach(function(res) {
    var match, resp = {};
    while(match = regex.exec(res))
      resp[match[2]] = match[3].toLowerCase();

    result.response.push(resp);
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(parse(json));
// =>
//{ response: 
//   [ { Name: '1', local: 'value1', remote: 'value2', state: 'active' },
//     { Name: '2', local: 'value3', remote: 'value4', state: 'active' } ] }
```